# Average speed wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, timer

i'm trying to do a average speed of bugs killed per min. This is my code now but its throwing an error saying string input format is wrong. Any advice? I'm using C# for WPF.

```
//Score is the number of bugs hit
score.Text = (_killings * 1).ToString();
//Change it to integer
int x = Int32.Parse(score.Text);
int y = Int32.Parse(TBCountdown.Text); - this is where the error is showing
//Get the average speed by dividing number of bugs hit during the time
int average = (x / y);
//Displaying the average score by converting int to string
averagescore.Text = average.ToString();
```

For more information, i'm using a dispatcher timer and this is my code for the timer.

```
TBCountdown.Text = string.Format("00:0{0}:0{1}", time / 60, time % 60);
```

Comment: How are you expecting to convert TBCountdown.Text to an Integer, it looks like it is formatted as a time. What portion of that value are you wanting to convert to your y data point?

Comment: just the minutes and seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things that are wrong with your code, I am presuming that you are incrementing a variable and using it to create an elapsed time of some sort. The first thing to state is that Ed S. is correct and you should not be using your UI to store your value, create a backing variable and work with that. As far as your issues: the first one that comes to mind that I mentioned in my comments is that you are trying to convert a string that looks like a TimeSpan to an integer, the second is that your Format String will not convert to a DateTime Object it comes up with a Format Exception Error. I was able to get your code to work by changing your Timer's Tick eventhandler to this.

```
DateTime temp = DateTime.Parse(string.Format("00:{0}:{1}", time / 60, time % 60));
TBCountdown.Text = temp.ToString("00:mm:ss");
```

and you can use something like this to get your Y value (*you did not respond to me about what information you were wanting for value*)

```
int y = (int)TimeSpan.Parse(TBCountdown.Text).TotalSeconds;
```

There is a lot of conjecture here about what you want, if this isn't correct please let us know.

Comment: I just need the time to get the average speed. For eg, if timer is stop at 2 minutes. the average speed will be divided from the bugs killed and 2 minutes. Sorry for being confusing here.

Comment: I tried your method. It's not showing an error anymore but my average speed is still not calculated.

Comment: @user3098072. What are your getting, put a breakpoint on the line that does the calculation and look at your values. I answered what was wrong, it wasn't clear what you were doing.

Comment: @user3098072. You are also dividing integers so the result will be an integer also, therefore 199 bugs divided by 200 seconds will still be zero. Look at changing your data type from an integer to a double.

Comment: Thanks for all the advice! It worked. I must also change it to double for it to have a result. Thanks!

Comment: @user3098072 You are welcome, Glad I was able to help

Answer (score 0):

This is how you format the textbox:

```
TBCountdown.Text = string.Format("00:0{0}:0{1}", time / 60, time % 60);
```

And then you try to parse that as an int.  Well, it's not an int.  Parse it back as a DateTime or, better yet, just use the variable you already have (`time`). In general it is a poor idea to rely on your UI for storing your data.  The UI is for display.

```
int y = time;
```

Comment: you are copy/pasting his code that is failing and telling him that is exactly how to do it???

Comment: @user2930100: I assume you didn't bother to read the paragraph under the line of code.

Comment: no i didn't read the paragraph underneath it that you added after I made the comment.

Comment: @user2930100: Nope, sure didn't. That text was in the original post.

Answer (score -2):

```
TBCountdown.Text = string.Format("00:0{0}:0{1}", (time / 60).ToString(), (time % 60).ToString());
```

remember this is a string function

Comment: That will still fail. The problem is trying to parse it as an int.  Also, the arguments are converted to strings by the method, your `ToString()` calls are redundant.  It takes a variable number of `object`s for a reason...